# PutAsync without altering content of CSV file

Tags: c#, csv, httpclient

I am trying to use HttpClient with putasync to send file to server. The function looks like:

```
public async Task SendCsvFile(string path,string apiKey)
       {
            try
            {
                string clientKey = "";
                LoggerService.Logger.CreateLog("Log");
                LoggerService.Logger.Info("Start:SendCsvFile");
                FileStream fileStream = null;
                HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
                clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
                HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();   
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-api-key", clientKey);
                string url = "https://test.csv";
                var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
                fileStream = File.OpenRead(path);
                StreamContent streamContent = new StreamContent(fileStream);
                content.Add(new StreamContent(fileStream), fileName, fileName);
                var response = await httpClient.PutAsync(url, content);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode == true)
                {

                    LoggerService.Logger.Info("File sent correctly.");
                }
                else
                {
                    LoggerService.Logger.Error("Error during sending." + response.StatusCode + ";" + response.ReasonPhrase + ";");
                }
                fileStream.Close();
                LoggerService.Logger.Info("End:SendCsvFile");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LoggerService.Logger.Error(ex.ToString());
                //return 0;
            }
          

            //return 1;

        }
```

File is send fine and it works however Content-disposition header is added to the file to the first line, and client doesn't want that. It's the first time I am doing anything with services and I read through a lot but still I don't know what can i change to not alter the content of csv file.

EDIT.
After I send the file header is added to the content so the file looks like that.
[Screenshot from client server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQ1Oz.png)

All the data is fine, though the client server processes the data in a way that it should start from column names. So my question really is what can I can change to omit that first line and is it even possible. Maybe thats something obvious but i' m just a newbie in this stuff.

Comment: Are you sure the file doesn't have that already? I can't see how that would happen. Have you tried various test files?

Comment: Use `MultipartContent` instead maybe? Side note: you are missing a bunch of `using` blocks to dispose various objects

Answer (score 0):

Changing to MultipartContent and Clearing Headers almost work but left me with boundary still visible in a file. Eventually I changed to RestSharp and adding content this way got rid of the problem.

```
 public async Task SendCsvFile(string path, string apiKey)
        {
            try
            {
                string clientKey = "";
                string url = "";
                LoggerService.Logger.CreateLog("CreationAndDispatchStatesWithPrices");
                LoggerService.Logger.Info("Start:SendCsvFile");
                FileStream fileStream = null;
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
                fileStream = File.OpenRead(path);

                var client = new RestClient(url);
                //            client.Timeout = -1;
                var request = new RestRequest();
                request.AddHeader("x-api-key", clientKey);
                request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/csv");
                request.AddParameter("text/csv", File.ReadAllBytes(path), ParameterType.RequestBody);
                RestResponse response = client.Put(request);

                if (response.IsSuccessful == true)
                {

                    LoggerService.Logger.Info("File sent correctly.");
                }
                else
                {
                    LoggerService.Logger.Error("Error sending file." + response.StatusCode + ";" + response.ErrorMessage + ";");
                }
                fileStream.Close();
                LoggerService.Logger.Info("End:SendCsvFile");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LoggerService.Logger.Error(ex.ToString());
                //return 0;
            }


            //return 1;

        }
```